# Download MailKit attachment with Angular 11

Tags: angular, .net-core, mailkit

I have an Angular 11 application with a .NET Core back end. The back end handles retrieving the emails from the server like this:

```
var message = await mailFolder.GetMessageAsync(UID);
var attachments = new List<CNCOrderEmailAttachment>();
foreach (var messageAttachment in message.Attachments)
{
  var fileName = messageAttachment.ContentDisposition.FileName ?? messageAttachment.ContentType.Name;

  using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
  {
    if (messageAttachment is MimePart)
      ((MimePart) messageAttachment).Content.DecodeTo(memory);
    else
      ((MessagePart) messageAttachment).Message.WriteTo(memory);

    var bytes = memory.ToArray();

    attachments.Add(new OrderEmailAttachment()
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        FileBinary = bytes,
        Type = messageAttachment.ContentType.MimeType
    });
  }
}
```

and stores them in an array of my OrderEmailAttachment class:

```
public class CNCOrderEmailAttachment
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileBinary { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

this returns them to the Angular 11 front end which transforms the byte array into a blob and tries to download it.

```
downloadFile(attachment: any){
  let blob = new Blob([attachment.fileBinary], { type: attachment.type });
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.download = attachment.fileName;
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

but when I try and open the attachment that has downloaded I always get an error that the file is corrupted. I have also tried:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(attachment.fileBinary.length);
var data = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var len = data.length, x;
for(x = 0; x < len; x++){
  data[x] = attachment.fileBinary.charCodeAt(x);
}

const blob = new Blob([data], { type: attachment.type });
```

but no matter what I try to do with the byte array the file is always corrupted.

Comment: If you save the contents of the byte[] to a file locally and then try to load it, does it work? If not, what are the contents?

Comment: Yeah, that works ok Must be the handover to Angular